# Trying to get 1 item to expand on hover in a flexbox container. Instead all Items in container expand

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular7

My desired effect is to have an item (link) in a flexbox container to grow or expand slightly on a hover, but instead the whole row of items grow when I hover on a single item.  I've been trying to do this by increasing the padding, as you'll see below.

My HTML template is using Angular 2+ syntax, but it's not hard to follow. Just getting a list of links dynamically from a for loop.

Any help, suggestions or useful links would be greatly appreciated!

My CSS is as follows ~

```
.page-flex-link {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
bottom: 1rem;
left: 10%;
position: absolute;
}

.page-flex-link > div {
background-color: #28a745;
border-radius: 50%;
padding: .5rem;
margin-left: .2rem;
margin-right: .2rem;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: .2rem .2rem .2rem grey;
}

.page-flex-link > div:hover {
background-color: #0f82db;
padding: .6rem;
box-shadow: .3rem .3rem .3rem grey;
}

.pli-text {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

My angular 7 HTML template is as follows~

```
<div class="page-flex-link">
  <div *ngFor="let page of lesson.pages"
    (click)="goToPage(page.pageNum)">
    <a class="pli-text" routerLink="/lessons/{{lesson.id}}/pages/{{page.pageNum}}">{{page.pageNum}}</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.page-flex-link` container calculates its dimensions based on its children. When you increase the padding of a child, it increases the overall dimensions of the container too.

An easy solution would be to use CSS `transform: scale()` instead of increasing padding. The `scale()` will increase the rendered size of the element, but won't increase its calculated dimensions:

```css
.page-flex-link {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
}

.page-flex-link > div {
  background-color: #28a745;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
  margin-right: 0.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0.2rem 0.2rem 0.2rem grey;
}

.page-flex-link > div:hover {
  background-color: #0f82db;
  /*padding: 0.6rem;*/
  transform: scale(1.2);
  box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.3rem grey;
}

.pli-text {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-flex-link">
  <div>
    <a class="pli-text">1</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="pli-text">2</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="pli-text">3</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="pli-text">4</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="pli-text">5</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="pli-text">6</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="pli-text">7</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="pli-text">8</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```